# Can't install Nokogiri or boot rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, nokogiri

I can't boot up my Rails server or install a gem. I'm not sure if I screwed something up with permissions but these are the errors I'm getting.

When I try to boot up the server I get this error message:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': 

Could not find 'nokogiri' (>= 1.5.9) among 267 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/GrandsonBoom/.gem/ruby/2.2.0:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0', execute `gem env` for more information

from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1311:in `block in activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `each'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in `activate'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1314:in `block in activate_dependencies'
```

I tried to install Nokogiri with `gem install nokogiri` and got this message:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen 
- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/.autotest
```

Then I tried `sudo gem install nokogiri` and got:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170225-28081-15v8ezo.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv using --with-opt-* flags... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
    [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
    [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
unsigned short* in = (unsigned short*) inb;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
encoding.c:815:27: warning: cast from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned short *' increases required alignment from 1 to 2 [-Wcast-align]
unsigned short* out = (unsigned short*) outb;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
CC       error.lo
CC       parserInternals.lo
CC       parser.lo
CC       tree.lo
CC       hash.lo
CC       list.lo
CC       xmlIO.lo
xmlIO.c:1450:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_OK'
ret =  (__libxml2_xzclose((xzFile) context) == LZMA_OK ) ? 0 : -1;
                                               ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--help
--clean
--use-system-libraries
--enable-static
--disable-static
--with-zlib-dir
--without-zlib-dir
--with-zlib-include
--without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
--with-zlib-lib
--without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
--enable-cross-build
--disable-cross-build
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed tocomplete compile task (RuntimeError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
from extconf.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
from extconf.rb:363:in `block in process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
from extconf.rb:547:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/gem_make.out
```

Here is my Ruby environment too:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5.1
- RUBY VERSION: 2.2.3 (2015-08-18 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-darwin14]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/GrandsonBoom/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86_64-darwin-14
- GEM PATHS:
 - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
 - /Users/GrandsonBoom/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
 - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
 - /usr/local/bin
 - /usr/bin
 - /bin
 - /usr/sbin
 - /sbin
 - /usr/local/git/bin
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev
```

And check here:

https://github.com/chef/chef-dk/issues/278

Comment: The OP is using Mac OS. `sudo apt-get install...` isn't used with Mac OS.